# Finding repetition patterns in list (python)

Tags: python, list, pattern-matching, networkx, random-walk

I need your help. I'm trying to find repetition patterns in lists (python).
I'm running a deterministic walk over a network and at each step, the function **trajectory()** saves the last visited node into the list **A**

Ex:  A = [0, 1, 4, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]

The trajectory can be compound by a transient in which there are no repetition patterns, and a cycle, in which the walker gets stuck in a loop.
In the example above, the transient is the sublist t = [0,1,4,6] from A, and the cycle is the sublist C = [1,2].

The cycle should repeat three times in sequence to stop the walking.

I need a function that receives a list A with all visited nodes and verifies if there is some cycle (of arbitrary size), and if this cycle repeats three times in sequence the function returns the sublist of the transient (ex [0,1,4,6]) and the cycle sublist (only the first appearance, ex [1, 2]). Furthermore, it sends a message (**True**/**False**) to the main function to stop the walking.
This function should be called at each step of the walking to verify if exist a cycle.

Comment: Please clarify input, output

Comment: Can have the cycles arbitrary length?

Comment: You can convert the list to a string and use regular expression